# Pygame image screen fill

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pygame program that is meant to fill the pygame window with Grass.png:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([600, 500])

def DrawBackground(background, xpos, ypos):
    screen.blit(background, [xpos, ypos])

background = pygame.image.load('Grass.png')
xpos = 0
ypos = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    while ypos >= -500:
        while xpos <= 600:
            DrawBackground(background, xpos, ypos)
            xpos += 100
        ypos -= 100

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Only problem is, it only fills the first 100 pixel row with the image. What is wrong with the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off using for loops rather than while loops to do that.

```
for y in range(5):
    for x in range(6):
        DrawBackground(background, x*100, y*100)
```

Makes the code much more readable and easier to debug. 
But in answer to your question, like frr171 said, the origin point (0, 0) is in the **top left** corner of the screen. As you go right, the x axis increases and as you go **down** the y axis increases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The y-axis is positive as you go down the screen - so while your first row is at a y-position of 0, the next row will be at a y-position of 100. Basically, you should be adding to the y-coordinate, not subtracting.